# checking email or user name if already exitst using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have create a form which contain just only one input tag which name is first_name .

Now I want to show the first_name is either exist in database or not.

I have create a database name db_practice ,table which name is tbl_user and there are many field. first_name is one of the field name.

Here is my all code. Please help me to find out my problem.

This is view code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Check username availability using jQuery, AJAX</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#username").live("blur", function(e) {
            $('#msg').hide();
            if ($('#username').val() == null || $('#username').val() == "") {
                $('#msg').show();
                $("#msg").html("Username is required field.").css("color", "red");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>"+"/welcome/get_user",
                    data: $('#signupform').serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $('#msg').show();
                        $("#msg").html(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#msg').show();
                        $("#msg").html(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px;width: 600px">
            <h3>Codeigniter username availability check</h3>
            <form id="signupform" style="padding: 10px;">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Check username</legend>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="username"/>
                        <div id="msg"></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="<?php echo assets_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo assets_url(); ?>js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo assets_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.10.3-custom.min.js">
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
<!-- below jquery things triggered on onblur event and checks the username availability in the database -->
```

This is controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('my_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
        public function get_user()
    {             
          if (isset($_POST['first_name']))
              {
                $username = $_POST['first_name'];
                $results = $this->my_model->get_user($username);
                if ($results === TRUE)
                    {
                        echo '<span style="color:red;">Username unavailable</span>';
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            echo '<span style="color:green;">Username available</span>';
                        }
             } 
             else {
                    echo '<span style="color:red;">Username is required field.</span>';
                  }
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

This is model code:

```
<?php

/*  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates  * and open the template in the editor.  */

/**  * Description of my_model  *  * @author Masud  */ class My_Model extends CI_Model {
    //put your code here
    public function get_user($username)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_user');
        $this->db->where('first_name',$username);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row();
        if ($result)
        {
         return TRUE;
        }
        else 
         {
            return FALSE;
        }

        } }

?>
```

Comment: No need to use block quote

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

1. In view: `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"/welcome/get_user",`
2. In controller:  `$results = $this->my_model->get_user($username); // not My_model, it's my_model`
3. In model:

   1. `class My_model extends CI_Model {  // My_model not My_Model`
   2. `$result = $query->row();           // $query, not $query_result`

Comment: I have completed what you tolled for correction but in yet it does not work. May be My ajax link does not work.

Comment: Open inspect element, go to network tab & check whether ajax request is being sent or not.

Comment: open google chrome, right click on the webpage & select inspect element, then at the top there are some tabs like element, network, sources, timeline etc. Select the network tab. Then trigger your event & observe for requests.

Comment: all js file show 404 when i click the preview menu then it show 404 page not find. But just only html tag active it indicate green color.  Please help

Comment: First, Make sure that jquery is loading. Then, make sure it is loading before the ajax request function. write console.log("test"); at different lines of the $("#username").live("blur", function(e) function to test. Open inspect element & console tab to check your log.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes and see.

In the Ajax code, `url: "<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/get_user",`

After the ajax code segment put

```
return false;
```

After adding those your javascript will be like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#username").live("blur", function(e) {
            $('#msg').hide();
            if ($('#username').val() == null || $('#username').val() == "") {
                $('#msg').show();
                $("#msg").html("Username is required field.").css("color", "red");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/get_user",
                    data: $('#signupform').serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $('#msg').show();
                        $("#msg").html(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#msg').show();
                        $("#msg").html(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
                
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have post a problem where input tag contain username from user .If this user name is already exist in data base then it will show Username Unavailable and the username not exist in database then it show Username Available.I share its solution ...............

This code for View

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Check username availability using jQuery, AJAX</title>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            //Create a boolean variable to check for a valid Internet Explorer instance.
            var xmlhttp = false;
            //Check if we are using IE.
             try {
            //If the Javascript version is greater than 5.
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            //alert ("You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer.");
                 } catch (e) {
            //If not, then use the older active x object.
                             try {
            //If we are using Internet Explorer.
                                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            //alert ("You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer");
                                 } catch (E) {
            //Else we must be using a non-IE browser.
                                    xmlhttp = false;
                                }
                            }
            //If we are using a non-IE browser, create a javascript instance of the object.
                    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
                         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //alert ("You are not using Microsoft Internet Explorer");
                                    }
            function makerequest( user_name,objID)
              {
                  if (user_name.length  == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Username available";
                    return;
                } else{
                //var user_name = document.getElementById('username').value;
                serverPage='welcome/valid_user_name/'+user_name;
                //alert(serverPage);
                xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                 {
                //alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                    //alert(xmlhttp.status);
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                         {
                                document.getElementById(objID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                //document.getElementById(objcw).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                         }
                }
             }
                xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
//-->                        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0 0 10px;width: 600px">
            <h3>Codeigniter username availability check</h3>
            <form id="signupform" style="padding: 10px;">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Check username</legend>
                    <div>
                        <label>Username</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name"
                           id="username" onkeyup="makerequest(this.value,'msg')"/>
                        <span id="msg"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email Address</label><br/>
                        <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email_address"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code for controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('my_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

        public function valid_user_name($user_name)
        {
           $result = $this->my_model->get_user($user_name);
           if ($result === TRUE)
                    {
                        echo '<span style="color:red;">Username unavailable</span>';
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            echo '<span style="color:green;">Username available</span>';
                        }
             } 
}
```

This code for model

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of my_model
 *
 * @author Masud
 */
class My_Model extends CI_Model {
    //put your code here
    public function get_user($user_name)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_user');
        $this->db->where('first_name',$user_name);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row();
        if ($result)
        {
         return TRUE;
        }
        else 
         {
            return FALSE;
        }

        }
}

?>
```

These codes are proved. Any body can use it..